# polynomial parametric surface is contained in an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. $f(u,v)$, $g(u,v)$ and $h(u,v)$ are polynomials of degree $\le n$.

For $m$ large enough, show that there exists a polynomial $p(x,y,z)$ in $k[x,y,z]$ of degree $\le m$ such that

$$p(f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v))= 0$$

that is,  the polynomial parametric surface $(f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v))$ is contained in an affine variety defined by $p(x,y,z)\in k[x,y,z]$

ps.  [affine variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety) is defined as the solution set to some polynomials in the affine space $k^n$.

Comment: $f, g, h$ define a morphism $k^2\to k^3$, $(u,v)\mapsto (f(u,v), g(u,v), h(u,v))$. Its image is not dense because $\dim k^2=2 < \dim k^3=3$. So the image is contained is some non-trivial hypersurface $p(x,y,z)=0$. This means that $p(f,g,h)(u,v)=0$.

Comment: This is the exercise II.1.5(d) from Cox, Little and O'Shea, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the space of polynomials in two variables with degree at most $mn$. This is a vector space of dimension $\binom{mn+2}{2},$ quadratic in $m.$ Now consider the set of polynomials $f^ig^jh^k$, with $i+j+k \le m.$ There are $\binom{m+3}{3}$ such monomials, cubic in $m$, so if $m$ is large there are going to be a linear combination of these which is zero, as desired.

Comment: Good answer, +1.