# Linearly dependent polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I am working on an algebra question which I don't quite understand what the question is even saying.

**A little context.** This is a question about "showing that all polynomial parametric curves in $k^2$ are contained in affine algebraic varieties" which has part a), b), c). I am stuck on b).

a) Show that the number of distinct monomials $x^ay^b$ of $\deg \leq m$ in $k[x,y]$ is equal to $\frac {(m+1)(m+2)}{2}$.
I have done this.

**Here is where I am stuck.**

> Show that if $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are polynomials of degree $\leq n$ in $t$, then for $m$ large enough, the "monomials" $[f(t)]^a[g(t)]^b$ with $a+b \leq m$ are linearly dependent.

First of all $f(t),g(t)$ are said to be polynomials and I don't see how $[f(t)]^a[g(t)]^b$ can be regarded as a "monomial". It seems like it's asking for a linear dependence over the field $k$ but even so... My understanding is that a linear dependence means that for some linear combination, the coefficients are NOT all $0$ for it to equal $0$.

My instructor gave a hint(?) that said consider $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=t^2$ but I still get nowhere because what, in this case, am I supposed to prove, for large enough $m$, that $c_1[f(t)]^a+c_2[g(t)]^b=c_1t^a+c_2t^{2b}=0$ that this is linearly dependent?

If anyone understands what this question is asking, please please clarify and give me some ideas... Help is more than appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287140/all-polynomial-parametric-curves-in-k2-are-contained-in-affine-algebraic-vari

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531155/polynomial-parametric-surface-is-contained-in-an-affine-variety

Comment: This is the exercise II.1.5(b) from Cox, Little and O'Shea, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prove that there exist $\alpha_{a,b}\in k$ not all zero such that $$\sum_{a+b\le m}\alpha_{a,b}f(t)^ag(t)^b=0.$$ If we denote by $p(x,y)$ the polynomial $\sum_{a+b\le m}\alpha_{a,b}x^ay^b$, then the above means that $p(x,y)\ne0$ and $p(f(t),g(t))=0$.

Now let $V_{mn}$ be the $k$-vector space of polynomials in one variable (say $t$) of degree less or equal than $mn$. We have $\dim V_{mn}=mn+1$. Now consider the $k$-vector space $W_m$ of polynomials in two variables (say $x,y$) of total degree at most $m$. By sending $x$ to $f(t)$, and $y$ to $g(t)$ we get a $k$-vector space homomorphism $\phi:W_m\to V_{mn}$. For large enough $m$ we have $\dim W_m>\dim V_{mn}$, and then $\ker\phi\ne\{0\}$ hence there is $p\in W_m$, $p\ne0$ such that $\phi(p)=0$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I've read and tried what you've done but I just don't see how this really leads to linear dependence...

Comment: @Kydo Maybe now is more clear: $\phi(p(x,y))=p(f(t),g(t))$ and $p(x,y)$ is a sum of monomials of the form $x^ay^b$ with $a+b\le m$.

Comment: Hi, thanks, finally...I got it. Appreciate your help, I don;t know how to choose this "best answer" thing though, I can't see a button or anything....